# iPhone nsarray first item should not add

Tags: iphone

I am parsing a XML file and reading its value.

I have value like "Select,1,2,3,4".

I read the above values as [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","] and stored in NSArray

Now , i want the values 1,2,3,4 to be stored in NSArray not the "Select" value

how to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *tail = [components mutableCopy];
[tail removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Now `tail` contains only the last count-1 objects from components.

Comment: :last row of array is retruning as "",Now my looks like 1,2,3,4,"". I don't want null to be returned

Answer (score 3):

[NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

```
NSArray *all = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange( 1, [all count] - 1 );

NSArray *result = [all getObjects: all range: range];
```

all will be autoreleased when your app's current event processing is finished.

If you're going to have large arrays, consider instead using an NSMutableArray so there will be less memory allocation.  NSArray is not mutable so the best you can do is create a new array with fewer elements.  The mutable arrays allow you to delete individual items from an existing array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as -

```
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    NSMutableArray *tmpArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 1; i < [array count]; i++) 
    {
        [tmpArr addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    NSArray *finalArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tmpArr];
```